# How to join tables on conditionally manipulated column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to manipulate my machine column to remove the leading zero when the make is AA. I then need to join all my tables. I can do each step individually but I do not know how to perform everything in one sql statement. I do not have the ability to create new tables. Here are examples of my tables. All tables have over 20 columns.

table1

```
CUNO   CUNM              OtherColumnsT1
1      Joe Construction  Blah
2      City of A         Blah
3      City of B         Blah
```

table2

```
Make  Machine   CUNO   OtherColumnsT2
AA    0123      3      Blah
ZZ    J623      2      Blah
AA    0124      2      Blah
KK    0241      1      Blah
```

table3

```
SerialNum  HeaderID  OtherColumnsT3
J623       1         Blah
123        2         Blah
0241       3         Blah
124        4         Blah
```

table4

```
HeaderID  SegmentID  Color  OtherColumnsT4
1         1          R      Blah
1         2          G      Blah
1         3          Y      Blah
2         1          G      Blah
2         2          G      Blah
3         1          R      Blah
4         1          G      Blah
```

With some help I was given this code which does a great job of manipulating the Machine column and merging it with table 3.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table2 m
INNER JOIN table3 c
ON m.Machine=c.SerialNum
WHERE m.Machine<>'AA'
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM table2 m
INNER JOIN table3 c
ON RIGHT(m.Machine,LEN(m.Machine) - 1)=c.SerialNum
WHERE m.Make='AA'
```

I still need to join tables 1 and 4 however.

I have tried adding more UNIONs to the above code but that threw me some errors.

I am looking for a table that ends up like this

```
CUNO CUNM              Make Machine HeaderID  OtherColumnsT3 SegmentID Color OtherColumnsT4
1    Joe Construction  KK   0241    3         Blah           1         R     Blah
2    City of A         ZZ   J623    1         Blah           1         R     Blah
2    City of A         ZZ   J623    1         Blah           2         G     Blah
2    City of A         ZZ   J623    1         Blah           3         Y     Blah
2    City of A         AA   124     4         Blah           1         G     Blah
3    City of B         AA   123     2         Blah           1         G     Blah
3    City of B         AA   123     2         Blah           2         G     Blah
```

Comment: The condition logic can easily be wrapped up in a `case` expression: `... on case when m.Machine = 'AA' then substring(m.Machine, 2, 10) else m.Machine end = c.SerialNum`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
select t1.CUNO, t1.CUNM, t2.Make, t2.Machine, t3.HeaderID, t4.SegmentID, t4.Color
from t1
join t2 on t2.CUNO = t1.CUNO
join t3 on ((t3.SerialNum = t2.Machine and len(t3.SerialNum) = len(t2.Machine)) or
(('0' + t3.SerialNum) = t2.Machine and len(t3.SerialNum) = 3))
join t4 on t4.HeaderId = t3.HeaderID
order by t1.CUNO
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simplify the `join` logic to:

```
 on t2.Machine = t3.SerialNum or
    (t2.Machine = '0' + t3.SerialNum and t2.make = 'AA')
```

or even:

```
on t2.Machine in (t3.SerialNum, '0' + t3.SerialNum)
```

I'm not sure if `AA` is really required.

The major caveat is that using such expressions in a `JOIN` generally kills performance.  If this is an issue, then you should ask another question specifically about performance.